# Locate Homebrew Repository on Mac OSX

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to follow the instructions [listed here for updating Homebrew](http://jcvangent.com/fixing-homebrew-os-x-10-10-yosemite/). Part of the instructions says:

> Simply type in the following: cd $(brew –repository) && git commit -a
>   -m ‘new ruby version 2.0′

How do I find where my brew repository is?

Comment: `brew -repository` should tell you where it is.

Comment: It didn't recognize the command

Comment: I assume you really have homebrew installed? What happens if you type `which brew`?

Comment: That should be `brew --repository` with *two* dashes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Homebrew's repository is usually in /usr/local. I think the trouble you're having comes from copying and pasting the text directly from that blog -- it's supposed to be

```
cd $(brew --repository) && git commit -a -m 'new ruby version 2.0'
```

but the blog engine "helpfully" replaced `--` with `–`, an [n dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash). (I would have expected it to make it an m dash, but that's beside the point.)

Type that line in verbatim and you should be fine. Or you could replace the `$(brew --repository)` part with `/usr/local` if you installed Homebrew in the default way.

Comment: Ah, the `--`-to-n-dash convention is used in TeX, where m dash is `---`; so I guess there was precedent for the blog engine to make that substitution.

Comment: Perfect perfect perfect. And yes, I managed to find the repo in usr/local, too. Thanks!